# Control new TCP Connections from all Clients together by some number

Tags: tcp

I wanted to control new TCP connections requests coming from all clients together by some 3 new connections per second.

What I wanted to know is that if I set below rule,

iptables -N syn_flood

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j syn_flood

iptables -A syn_flood -m limit --limit 3/s --limit-burst 3 -j RETURN

iptables -A syn_flood -j DROP

will it control new TCP Connections, together from all clients(IP, Port) to 3 new connections/second
OR
New TCP connection from each client(IP, Port) it will limit to 3/second?

I have some 500 clients that may connect to the server.
So I wanted to control that at new moment from all these 500 clients together the server should accept only 3 new connections/sec.

But I have a feeling that the above rule set control connections from each client by 3 new connections/sec. That is, if I have 500 clients, then it will accept 500x3 new connections/sec.
Please let me know the correct behaviour.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: *"But I have a feeling ...."* - what makes your feel this way? Your rule simple limits the total number of packets with a SYN flag set, i.e. not specific to source IP/port.